# Multiple mysqli_query not executed in same connection without closing connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an issue with the following statement. No error is produced but my second mysqli_query is not being executed. In my previous project, I was forced to close and reopen the connection to the database before executing a new query but I'd like to believe that it's not very smart to close and reopen connections to a database several times in a script. Is there a way to go around this ?

Secondly, I've included my connection script in a separate file. So, should I close it after the first mysqli_query, how do I reopen it to be able to execute the second(subsequent) mysqli_query? I've thought of creating my own function that'll reopen the connection but I want to stay away from opening and closing database connections several times in a single script if possible.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = '$email'"; 
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die (mysqli_error($dbc));
if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0){ 

    $queryInsertMember = "INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$surname', SHA('$confirmedPassword'), '$gender', '$telMobile')";

    mysqli_query($dbc, $queryInsertMember) or die (mysqli_error($dbc)); 

    $queryInsertAddress = "INSERT INTO address VALUES ('$email', '$hzNumber', '$streetName', '$suburb', '$city', '$postalCode', '$province' , '')";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $queryInsertAddress) or die (mysqli_error($dbc)); 

} else {
    echo 'member already exists';
}
```

Comment: I'd say you are right - opening, closing, opening,closing db connections is not the best approach. Include the db connection from another file but leave the closing of the connection out of that file and call the relevant method in the script shown here once all queries have been done.

Comment: @RamRaider , I did choose to leave the closing of the connection out of the connection file. I want to close the connection to the database independently in each script with the mysqli_close() function

Comment: Which queries are not running?  Both inserts, or just the second insert?  If its both, are you sure the mysql_num_rows($data) is evaluating to 0?

Comment: @SilicaGel Yes the mysqli_num_rows does evaluate to 0. After a few hours I realized that the second query was not executed because of the structure of my address table. My first column in that tables has  auto_increment attribute but because in my SQL statement I don't specify which columns the data has to be added to, the server starts adding from the very first column which is the auto_increment which i'm assuming should not be allowed. The moment i specified which columns the data has to added to, the query that wasn't being executed, worked.

Comment: Good catch.  Another thing you can do, when inserting to an auto-incremented table without specifying columns, is to pass null in place of the auto-increment value, which will basically be ignored.  (I'm not sure if this is considered good practice or not though.)

Comment: @SilicaGel  Good question, is it considered good practice? I'm also not sure.